# Create multidimensional array based on value of key

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I have an `array` of `MyData` objects (`MyData` is a `struct`):

```
[
MyData(id: 3, locale: "en", title: "p1", date: "10/15/2019"), 
MyData(id: 3, locale: "de", title: "p2", date: "11/12/2019"), 
MyData(id: 32, locale: "fr", title: "free", date: "10/11/2019"), 
MyData(id: 15, locale: "de", title: "free", date: "10/11/2019"), 
MyData(id: 19, locale: "de", title: "p1", date: "11/10/2019"),
MyData(id: 19, locale: "de", title: "p2", date: "11/10/2019"),
MyData(id: 19, locale: "de", title: "p3", date: "11/10/2019"),
]
```

I'd like to group this array (or even purposedly create a new one) based on the `id` key.

The result should be like this one:

```
[
[MyData(id: 3, locale: "en", title: "p1", date: "10/15/2019"), MyData(id: 3, locale: "de", title: "p2", date: "11/12/2019")], 
MyData(id: 32, locale: "fr", title: "free", date: "10/11/2019"), 
MyData(id: 15, locale: "de", title: "free", date: "10/11/2019"), 
[MyData(id: 19, locale: "de", title: "p1", date: "11/10/2019"),MyData(id: 19, locale: "de", title: "p2", date: "11/10/2019"),MyData(id: 19, locale: "de", title: "p3", date: "11/10/2019")]
]
```

that is: arrays having the same id should form a new array.

Of course, I could simply loop over the first array and create the second, but I wanted to know if there's something Swift can do with its filters.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: offtopic, struct naming as `Data` is not recommended

Comment: You are NOT offtopic, don't worry, it's a wise suggestion: the real name of my struct isn't even Data, i wrote Data here to help people better undestand the question. I change it to MyData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the higher order functions in this for sure, but not *100*% to fully produce the desired result but a big chunk of it, since your desired array type is `:[Any]`.

**Check out the code below:**

```
var myGroup = Dictionary(grouping: arrayOne, by: { $0.id }) // group each element by id -type of: [Int:[Data]]
let resultArray = myGroup.map { $0.value } //map out the elements without the id key. -type of: [[Data]]

//Create hetro Array so we can use it later to append the results
var myHetroArray: [Any] = []
// loop each array in the result array and check if it only contains 1 element if so append that one element to the hetro array otherwise just append the whole thing.
for array in resultArray {
    if array.count ==  1 {
    myHetroArray.append(array.first!)
    } else {
        myHetroArray.append(array)
    }
}

print(myHetroArray) // produce the desired result.
```

> **Output:** [
>   [Data(id: 19, locale: "de", title: "p1", date: "11/10/2019"),Data(id: 19, locale: "de", title: "p2", date: "11/10/2019"),Data(id: 19, locale: "de", title: "p3", date: "11/10/2019")],
>   Data(id: 15, locale: "de", title: "free", date: "10/11/2019"),
>   Data(id: 32, locale: "fr", title: "free", date: "10/11/2019"),
>   [Data(id: 3, locale: "en", title: "p1", date: "10/15/2019"), Data(id: 3, locale: "de", title: "p2", date: "11/12/2019")]
>   ]

Comment: It's ok. I'm not surprised there isn't a better way to do it but it's not important, since in any case it solves a server data issue (a JSON that can't be changed)

Comment: well if anything new came up to me ill edit the answer but i guess nothing would help pretty much even with high order functions you can't produce a heterogeneous type array

Answer (score 0):

There are two more ways. Just as a note here.

```
    struct MyData{
        let id : Int
        let locale : String
        let title : String
        let date : String
    }

    let data = [
        MyData(id: 3, locale: "en", title: "p1", date: "10/15/2019"),
        MyData(id: 3, locale: "de", title: "p2", date: "11/12/2019"),
        MyData(id: 32, locale: "fr", title: "free", date: "10/11/2019"),
        MyData(id: 15, locale: "de", title: "free", date: "10/11/2019"),
        MyData(id: 19, locale: "de", title: "p1", date: "11/10/2019"),
        MyData(id: 19, locale: "de", title: "p2", date: "11/10/2019"),
        MyData(id: 19, locale: "de", title: "p3", date: "11/10/2019"),
    ]


    data.reduce(into: [:]) { ( result, next) in
    if result.keys.contains(next.id){
        (result[next.id] as? [MyData]).map{result[next.id] =  $0 + [next] }
        ([result[next.id]] as? [MyData]).map{result[next.id] = $0 + [next]}
    }
    else{ result[next.id] = next }
}.values


    Set(data.map{$0.id}).map{id -> Any in
        let result = data.filter{$0.id == id}
        return result.count == 1 ? result.first! : result
    }
```