# Why isn't the last full stop removed from a stringArray using .map

Tags: arrays, swift

I am using Swift.
I am try to convert a sentence to a string array. I have used map to separate fullstops and commas from the word as follows:

```
extension String  {


func convertSentenceToArray()-> [String] {
var sentence = String(self)

sentence.index(of: ".").map { 
   sentence.remove( at: $0)
   sentence.insert(".", at: $0)
   sentence.insert(" ", at: $0)
   }
sentence.index(of: ",").map { 
  sentence.remove( at: $0)
  sentence.insert(",", at: $0)
  sentence.insert(" ", at: $0) 
   }
 return sentence.components(separatedBy: " ")
 }
}

let  thisSentenceString = "I am trying to create an array from a sentence. But I don't understand, Why isn't the last fullstop removed, from the last word."

let thisSentenceArray = thisSentenceString.convertSentenceToArray()

print(thisSentenceArray)
```

results in:

> ["I", "am", "trying", "to", "create", "an", "array", "from", "a", "sentence", ".", "But", "I", "don\'t", "understand", ",", "Why", "isn\'t", "the", "last", "fullstop", "removed,", "from", "the", "last", ***"word."***]

All the fullstops and commas are handled as I would expect except for the last.

I don't understand why the last full stop remains. While I can find a work around for this, I would like to understand what is wrong with the approach I have taken.

Comment: Your code handles (at most) *one* fullstop and *one* comma.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27870385/how-can-i-put-each-word-of-a-string-into-an-array-in-swift

Comment: it didn't remove the comma after "removed,"

Comment: Hint: `index(of:)` is returning an optional, so you're using `Optional.map`, *not* `Array.map`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First an explanation what your code does:

```
sentence
   .index(of: ".") // find the first index of the dot character
   .map {  // Optional.map, if the index exists, do the following
      sentence.remove( at: $0) // remove dot
      sentence.insert(".", at: $0) // insert dot again
      sentence.insert(" ", at: $0) // insert space
   }
```

or rewritten:

```
if let firstDotIndex = sentence.index(of: ".") {
    sentence.insert(" ", at: firstDotIndex)
}
```

That means only *the first* dot character is found and replaced.

To do this algorithm correctly, you would need:

```
// helper method checking punctuation to avoid code duplication
let isPunctuation: (Character) -> Bool = {
    return [".", ","].contains($0)
}

// initial range, we want to check the entire string
var range = sentence.startIndex...

// iterate while some punctuation exists
while let punctuationIndex = sentence[range].index(where: isPunctuation) {
    // insert the separator
    sentence.insert(" ", at: punctuationIndex)
    // search next punctuation only from the last replacement
    range = sentence.index(after: punctuationIndex)...
}
```

However, there is actually already a method for `String` replacement:

```
sentence = sentence.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: " .")
```

Or even simpler, with a regular expression to cover all punctuation characters in one go:

```
return self
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "[,.]", with: " $0", options: .regularExpression)
    .components(separatedBy: " ")
```

Comment: Really nice solution!!  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is slightly different than what you asked for, but depending upon why you’re doing this, you can consider the [NaturalLanguage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/naturallanguage) framework. E.g.

```
import NaturalLanguage

let text = "I am trying to create an array from a sentence. But I don't understand, Why isn't the last fullstop removed, from the last word."

var words: [String] = []

let tagger = NLTagger(tagSchemes: [.lexicalClass])
tagger.string = text
let options: NLTagger.Options = [.omitWhitespace, .joinContractions]
tagger.enumerateTags(in: text.startIndex..<text.endIndex, unit: .word, scheme: .lexicalClass, options: options) { tag, range in
    if let tag = tag {
        words.append(String(text[range]))
    }
    return true
}
print(words)
```

> ["I", "am", "trying", "to", "create", "an", "array", "from", "a", "sentence", ".", "But", "I", "don\'t", "understand", ",", "Why", "isn\'t", "the", "last", "fullstop", "removed", ",", "from", "the", "last", "word", "."]

What’s interesting about this is that the `tag` property will tell you the parts of speech, what’s a sentence terminator, etc., e.g.:

```
tagger.enumerateTags(in: text.startIndex..<text.endIndex, unit: .word, scheme: .lexicalClass, options: options) { tag, range in
    if let tag = tag {
        print(text[range], tag.rawValue)
    }
    return true
}
```

Producing:

> I Pronoun 
>   am Verb 
>   trying Verb 
>   to Particle 
>   create Verb 
>   an Determiner 
>   array Noun 
>   from Preposition 
>   a Determiner 
>   sentence Noun 
>   . SentenceTerminator 
>   But Conjunction 
>   I Pronoun 
>   don't Verb 
>   understand Verb 
>   , Punctuation 
>   Why Pronoun 
>   isn't Verb 
>   the Determiner 
>   last Adjective 
>   fullstop Noun 
>   removed Verb 
>   , Punctuation 
>   from Preposition 
>   the Determiner 
>   last Adjective 
>   word Noun 
>   . SentenceTerminator

Or, perhaps you don’t really care about the punctuation and simply want to have this broken up into sentences and the sentences broken up into words:

```
var sentences: [[String]] = []

let sentenceTokenizer = NLTokenizer(unit: .sentence)
sentenceTokenizer.string = text

sentenceTokenizer.enumerateTokens(in: text.startIndex ..< text.endIndex) { range, _ in
    let sentence = String(text[range])
    let wordTokenizer = NLTokenizer(unit: .word)
    wordTokenizer.string = sentence

    let words = wordTokenizer.tokens(for: sentence.startIndex ..< sentence.endIndex)
        .map { String(sentence[$0]) }

    sentences.append(words)
    return true
}
print(sentences)
```

> [
>     ["I", "am", "trying", "to", "create", "an", "array", "from", "a", “sentence"], 
>     ["But", "I", "don\'t", "understand", "Why", "isn\'t", "the", "last", "fullstop", "removed", "from", "the", "last", “word"]
>   ]

There are lots of options here between `NLTagger` and `NLTokenizer`. Depending upon what problem you’re really trying to solve, these might be better than manipulating strings yourself.

---

As Sultan said, you can obviously just insert spaces and the `split` the string, though I might suggest adding other punctuation symbols and include `+` to match more or one characters in the case of consecutive punctuation marks (notably ellipses, `...`), e.g.

```
let words = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "[,.:;!?]+", with: " $0", options: .regularExpression)
    .split(separator: " ")
```

Comment: Rob - that is absolutely amazing I can see I am going to have to study the Natural Language framework!!  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this way:

```
 func convertSentenceToArray()-> [String] {
    var sentence = String(self)
 sentence =    sentence.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: " .")
 sentence =    sentence.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: " ,")
    return sentence.components(separatedBy: " ")
}
```

Comment: Good solution but still a bit too complicated `self.replacingOccurrences(of: "([,.])", with: " $1", options: .regularExpression)`. Using `var sentence` copy is now not necessary.

Comment: Many thanks  E.Coms solutions works for me, I think I must have been trying too hard to use .map!!!  Thanks again to everyone who replied

Comment: @sapjjr Thank you. As you teach me how to use optional.map to make code a little neat as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54441006/create-multidimensional-array-based-on-value-of-key/54445417#54445417

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more traditional and general approach:

```
func separateString(string: String) -> [String]{
    let stringArray = Array(string.unicodeScalars)
    var stringsArray: [String] = []

    let letterSet = CharacterSet.letters
    let punctuationSet = CharacterSet.punctuationCharacters

    var newWord = ""
    var newPunctioationChar = ""

    for char in stringArray {
        if letterSet.contains(char) {
            newWord.unicodeScalars.append(char)

        } else if punctuationSet.contains(char) {
            newPunctioationChar.unicodeScalars.append(char)

            stringsArray.append(contentsOf: [newWord, newPunctioationChar])

            newWord = ""
            newPunctioationChar = ""
        }
    }

     return stringsArray
}
```